# Ruby on Rails: How to attach a file to an email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api

I am trying to send an email with an attachment from my Rails project. I am using the Google API specifically the gmail_v1 API.

I have been able to get my code to send an email with a subject and a body, but have not been able to attach a CSV. The name of the CSV is "results.csv"

```
m = Mail.new(
  to: "to@gmail.com",
  from: "from@gmail.com",
  subject: "Test Subject",
  body:"Test Body")

  m.attachments['shoes.csv'] = {mime_type: 'results.csv', content: CSV}

  message_object = Google::Apis::GmailV1::Message.new(raw:m.to_s)
  service.send_user_message("me", message_object)
```

Without the line:

```
m.attachments['shoes.csv'] = {mime_type: 'results.csv', content: CSV}
```

The code works, but without the attachment. What is the correct way to add the attachment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending wrong arguments to the attachments.

attachments should be send as below

```
attachments['shoes.csv'] = { mime_type: 'text/csv', content: File.read("path/to/csv/or/generator/methos") }
```

Updated code will be as

```
m = Mail.new(
  to: "to@gmail.com",
  from: "from@gmail.com",
  subject: "Test Subject",
  body:"Test Body")

  m.attachments['shoes.csv'] = { mime_type: 'text/csv', content: File.read("path/to/csv/or/generator/methos") }

  message_object = Google::Apis::GmailV1::Message.new(raw:m.to_s)
  service.send_user_message("me", message_object)
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I am unsure about how to add the path. My file structure is as follows lib->tasks->csvSender. My csv is in my general project directory not in any specific folder. I have tried just 'results.csv', but that didn't work. What would the correct path be?

Comment: I have been trying this with multiple different directories, but every time the attached CSV file I receive is just made up of one value which is the path I put into content:.

Comment: Realized you needed to add a File.read() around the path of the file.